# product id does not show in firebase extension

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments

I am trying to install  Run Subscription Payments with Stripe using this tutorial - https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-stripe-subscriptions

```
 Now, the  product id. should be be created automatically, but neither the product nor the product-id  shows in firestore console as you can see below:-
```

[image]

The webhook are installed:-

[image]

Also, functions are deployed:-

[image]

Also, I  have added product with price in the stripe console:-

[image]

So, why iproduct or product-id is not showing in Firebase console( figure 1)

Comment: What makes you think that a total stranger will go to YouTube to watch a video just in order to assist you?  In case you didn't know, this isn't a YouTube video support site.

Comment: @ElTomato - I  have edited  the question.

Comment: There's probably a bug or typo in your code but without seeing it we'll never know. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I had not updated the rules correctly and not connected webhook correctly, now working fine. Make sure you follow each and every step in the document,